# How is network virtualization useful?

Tags: networking, sdn

I am trying to understand various virtualization techniques, and I am struggling to wrap my head around the concept of Network Virtualization. I don't have a networking background(mostly programming).

In case of the server virtualization, the objective is the most efficient use of hardware(using hypervisor), and the alternative is the under utilization of resources. Does that apply in case of network virtualization as well? Is it possible for routers/switches to be under-utilized like a computer's CPU?

Server virtualization uses hypervisor(like virtual box) in spinning up virtual machines. Does network virtualization also make use of hypervisors on top of networking hardware like routers/switches? I have done some research online, but it is not clear to me how hypervisors might factor in network virtualization,

Can somebody give me a high level idea of how network virtualization is implemented, and what benefits it gives.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to increasing hardware utilization, virtualization enables you to deploy new instances out of the thin air, even automated. It saves you the trouble of ordering additional hardware, waiting for delivery, unpacking and screwing it into a rack. This is the same for host and network virtualization. The latter may also use hypervisor technology, but most often that's not the case.

There's a large number of very different approaches and aspects. The usual first step to network virtualization are VLANs. Without them, you'd use dedicated, separate switches for networks/zones that you want segregated: one switch (tree) for PC clients, one for servers, one for IP phones, and so on. Each zone needs to provide the required number of ports, you cannot use a port from another zone because it's not connected as needed. Of course, each zone needs to provide separate interconnects between multiple switches as well.

With VLANs, you can use a shared infrastructure for all your zones - just assign a VLAN as port role as required. Interconnects use tagging across VLAN trunks, so there's no need for dedicated interconnects either. Apart from simplifying operations and deployment, VLANs enable you to use a much larger number of zones than would be practical with separated infrastructures.

VLANs virtualize the data link layer (OSI L2) - there's a great number of other functions that profit from virtual instances (virtual NICs to provide/improve host connectivity, virtual IPs for host/router failover or load balancing, virtual links between remote networks using tunneling, and so on). Software-defined networking (SDN) is a technology to abstract and virtualize all forms of network transportation as a whole.

In a nutshell: you can't operate a seriously sized network without virtualization.